# Why doesn't GNU's documentation list pubseekoff as a member of basic_streambuf?

Tags: c++, gcc

This question may be silly, but this is my very first incursion into gcc docs.

I know `basic_streambuf::pubseekoff()` is a public member function of template class `basic_streambuf` but it is not listed in [GNU's libstdc++ documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00258.html) as such. Why is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, the documentation parser has got it wrong and listed it as a *friend* function. If you follow the link to the source file at the bottom of the page and look at the source you will find `pubseekoff` as a member function as it should be.

See line 241: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01071_source.html

Comment: Wow, Doxygen's gone really wrong there!  I'll try to fix it. Thanks, Charles.